# When adding a new event, the socket does not see it

Tags: node.js, server, socket.io

When adding a new event, the socket does not see it, also if I just add the console log that the connection is established, it is also not displayed on the server.

```
// server.ts file
// some imports...
const nextApp = next({ dev: config.dev });
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST']
    }
});
io.on('connection', socket => socketServer(socket, io));
nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    app.use(compression)
    ...
    app.get('*', () => {/*handle*/})
    server.listen(config.port, (err) => {if (err) {}})
})
.catch((ex) => {
    console.error(`Server down. Reason: ${ex}`);
    process.exit(1);
});

// serverLogic file
export default (socket, io) => {
   console.log('Socket connected!!!'); // this new change(add console.log) that do not take effect
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you restart the server after changes?

Comment: I'm not very good at this but we are using pm2, I completely restarted this

Comment: All changes have taken effect, client and server (we have nextjs). But the added console.log io.on('connection) is not displayed, not to mention the new socket.on ()

Comment: Seems like you never call `listen`

Comment: post here a more detailed view of my server.ts?

Comment: this is my first experience with websockets. Maybe the location of server.listen() is wrong?

Comment: How do you import `socketServer`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249585/discussion-between-roman-nozhenko-and-konrad-linkowski).