# User 1 (with camera) does not transfer to User 2 (without camera), if the camera is turned on for both - everything is OK

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, webrtc

Stack: Nextjs, expressjs, socket.io, WebRTC

I'm trying to build a video chat, at the moment everything works fine only if the second user joins and agrees to use the camera and has one at all.
Otherwise, the connection is established, a chat is available between two users, but user 2 does not receive the video stream of user 1.

I put [this code](https://github.com/rRaijin/video-chat-webrtc/blob/master/src/hooks/useWebRTC.js) on github for more clarity and a better understanding of what is happening.

Very big cosmic thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling createOffer without the "legacy" offerToReceive* constraints. Without these, if the user creating the offer does not have a camera they will only negotiate audio and not attempt to negotiate video.

See https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/ for a sample using those options.

Comment: Very big cosmic thank you! Yes it really works now. Thank you for taking the time to view the repository I specified, tell me, in the process of viewing it, you did not find something that could affect the fact that my server part is not updated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430684/when-adding-a-new-event-the-socket-does-not-see-it

Comment: From a conversation with the system administrator, as I understand it, we just have a load balancer on AWS that only redirects traffic, and the reason is on the wrong side. Could this still be related to PM2? I just read somewhere that it needs to be removed and reinstalled if a socket is added, maybe I'm confusing something?